# How to create a pagecall counter in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to have a service which counts the amount a page was called.
My problem is that the service is newly instantiated each time I reload the page. Because it is allways 1.
I inject it inside my controller method and call the cont() function from there.

```
class CountService {
    private static $counter = 0;

    public static function count()
    {
        self::$counter++;

    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public static function getCounter(): int
    {
        return self::$counter;
    }
}
```

How can I persist the counter variable during the time the server stays on?
I dont want to use a database for this.

Comment: Inject the Session and keep the counter there. Either way you need some kind of persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dedicated entity for the counting since you need some form of persistance, you might also like to store a cookie with the information that user already visited the page since you probably dont want to count every time user refreshes the page

Comment: "you probably dont want to count every time user refreshes the page" This is exactly what I want. "you need some form of persistance" yea this is what I'm looking for with this question. I dont know a way to save data for the time the server runns except using databases.

Comment: If you dont want to run it with database maybe use some sort of json object? key is the page route / uri and then value is the views count and put it in a static file called "visits.json"? Use file_put_contents and file_get_contents to read / save the files every time kernel request is invoked, if you still dont get the idea answer my comment and I'll edit my answer and put some example code

Comment: I get the idea but is there really no other way to have a class/object that lives from the start of the program to the end like Singletons in other webframeworks?

Comment: You need some sort of persistance in between the requests, since all the data gets lost every time you request a new uri of your website. As said on the question comment you might also like to use session to store the value but when you would like to know what the end result of the value was you need to have a way to store it either in the database or in a file. The idea is farily simple you create a session, user does stuff the visits gets saved and then after he leaves your website the session goes bye bye and you have no idea what was there

Comment: Thanks now I get it. I used JaxRS Jersey before and there you could create Objects on server start and they got only deleted when you stopped the server and in the time between you could access and modify the object.